# Grey-out QLineEdit as per disabled state automatically, combined with non-conditional style sheet directive?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtstylesheets

By default, a `QLineEdit` is greyed-out when disabled.

If you set a stylesheet with a simple directive, e.g. setting a border, this cancels that default behaviour.

Fortunately it is possible to mimic the default behaviour, like so:

```
qle.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit[readOnly=\"true\"] {color: #808080; background-color: #F0F0F0;}')
```

But how might I *combine* this conditional greying-out with setting a border (unconditionally)?

Here is an MRE:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("QLE stylesheet question")
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 30)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        qle = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        qle.setObjectName('qle')
        # qle.setStyleSheet('border:4px solid yellow;')
        # this sets up the style sheet to reproduce the default PyQt behaviour for a QLE (greyed-out if disabled, otherwise not)
        # qle.setStyleSheet('QLineEdit[readOnly=\"true\"] {color: #808080; background-color: #F0F0F0;}')
        
        # doesn't work: when disabled is not greyed-out!
        qle.setStyleSheet('#qle {border:4px solid yellow;} #qle[readOnly=\"true\"] {color: #808080; background-color: #F0F0F0;}')
        
        # qle.setEnabled(False) # uncomment to see "disabled" appearance
        layout.addWidget(qle)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You're confusing *disabled* with *read only*. A QLineEdit can be read only but still enabled, for instance it can have some text that cannot be modified, but the user can select that text and eventually copy it. A disabled widget completely prevents user interaction. The [stylesheet examples](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlineedit) clearly show how to properly declare rules for the `:read-only` mode of QLineEdit, while the [overall reference](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states) shows the other available states (such as `:disabled`)